# Background blend mode issue with background attachment fixed

Tags: html, css

I have the following style in my css file to set the background of my html to a soothing gradient. However there was a problem that, if the height of the content is not 100% of the screen, the gradient gets cut off and repeats. So I added the `background-attachment: fixed;` line so that the gradient fills the page. But now the blend mode is not working. Earlier I had a soothing light color combination due to the `background-blend-mode: screen;` but now the colors are brighter. How can I fix this? I am using the latest version of mozilla firefox.

```
body {
    background:
        linear-gradient(
            cyan,
            transparent
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            magenta,
            transparent
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            45deg,
            orange,
            transparent
        );
    background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-attachment: fixed; //added later to fill the background
}
```

[**Here is the jsfiddle link.**](http://jsfiddle.net/f90vwhw3/)

Expected output

[image: Expected output]

What I am getting

[image: What I am getting]

Comment: It is working well for me on chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 32.0.3

Comment: It seems to be working for me correctly, but if you could post a photo of what is NOT the right look that would help. Don't know how much 'brighter' is as far as the color difference. I'm using FF 32.0.3 too.

Answer (score 0):

*with this your problem is solved*

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background:
        linear-gradient(
            cyan,
            rgba(255,255,255,0) 
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            magenta,
            rgba(255,255,255,0) 
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            45deg,
            orange,
            rgba(255,255,255,0) 
        );
    background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Comment: you are setting the height of the entire `document`. 
this works fine. 
is not the height of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the 'transparent' in your CSS was going to black-transparent. If you set it to white-transparent then you'll get the desired look. As Vals mentioned, black-transparent is the standard for future reference if you run into this problem again.

Take a look at the fiddle. Should sort you all out.

Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f90vwhw3/3/

CSS to fix:

```
body { 
        background:
                linear-gradient(
                        cyan ,
                        rgba(255,255,255,0) 
                ),
                linear-gradient(
                        -45deg,
                        magenta,
                        rgba(255,255,255,0) 
                ),
                linear-gradient(
                        45deg,
                        orange,
                        rgba(255,255,255,0) 
                );
        background-blend-mode: screen;
        background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

Comment: black transparent is the standard for *transparent*

Comment: @vals I realize that. I should have worded it differently, but the white transparent solves it. Didn't do a very good job explaining my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. Your answer is ok. I was only making clear that the rendering of transparent as black transparent follows w3c standard